# Determine value if function is differentiable

Tags: limits, functions

Consider
$$f\left( x\right) =ae^{x}+1$$ when x is less than 0 and
$$f\left( x\right) =x+b$$ when x is more than or equals to 0.

Determine the value of a and b if f(x) is differentiable on R

Here's what I have done.

For it to be differentiable, it must be continuous at x=0, and $$\dfrac {d}{dx}\left( ae^{x}+1\right) =\dfrac {d}{dx}\left( x+b\right)$$
So from the contirnous equation, I got $$a+1=b$$, while I got $$ae^x =1$$ for the other. How do I proceed?

Comment: If derivatives are equal you will get $a=1$ and from continuity $a+1=2=b$.

Comment: @Jon if derivatives are equal shouldn't I only get $$ae^x=1$$? How will I get a=1?

Comment: Evaluate at 0 just second equation. Remember you are looking at the detivatives at 0

Comment: @JoaquinSan oh my, I must be too tired, why did I not notice that, sighs. Thanks for the help though